# VS Code launch.json variables regex replacement

Tags: visual-studio-code

In launch.json I have a debug configuration that runs mocha for the current file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Mocha Current File",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
            "args": [
                "--timeout",
                "999999",
                "--colors",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        }   
    ]
}
```

I am using typescript and the ts file is at folder src/... root whereas the test.js file is at folder root dist/... I want to have the ts file open, run the debug mocha configuration and have rewrite the src path to the dist path.

The following gets met almost there: "dist/${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.js"

but relativeFileDirname still contains src/... as the root. I need to do a regex replacement.

Extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) has more or less what I need but it does directory up patterns whereas I need directory down patterns, ie it can take src/folder1/folder2 and return src/folder1 whereas I want folder1/folder2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `extension.commandvariable.transform` command.

```
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "down1Dir",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": {
        "text": "${relativeFileDirname}",
        "find": ".*?/(.*)",
        "replace": "$1",
      }
    }
  ]
```